# Virtual functions within link list's - multiple return types (object)

Tags: c++, linked-list, virtual

I have an assignment in uni to do, basically, we take in a bunch of data from many txt files. the data is structured in a way that it can be read, for this question ill cut it down to two files and two classes. an example of the data is this:

#### Faculty.txt ( PK, Name)

```
AT  Advanced Technology 
HESAS   Health, Sport and Science
```

#### Department.txt (PK, Name, FK)

```
ET  Engineering and Technology  AT  
BE  Built Environment   AT  
CMS Computing and Mathematical Sciences AT  
SAS Science and Sport   HESAS   
CS  Care Sciences   HESAS   
PESD    Professional Education and Service Delivery HESAS
```

The idea is to create report's using the data, the program is meant to use link lists, relationships and virtual functions. So in the code we basically have a list (im using FILO) of nodes-

-Out of context question-

(im not sure im getting the lectures provided node and list code concept we have been given - I say this because I cannot get my head around where node stores the memory address of the object. Unless im misunderstanding it and node is a child of each class it extends so it inherits everything from that class and add's its stuff on top? if that is the case why do we need to make a virtual function in the 1st place if we inherit all of the functionality - security?)

-that have pointers of objects stored inside them. now where im actually stuck is loading the data in - well iv loaded it all into lists fine, but i have only loaded the Foreign key's in as strings where as i need to basically check the string FK against the PK of the objects stored in the previous file iv loaded (the lecture went easy and gave us a easy 1-8 flow where 1 has no FK:)) and then when i find that object get its memory address and use that as the FK. the idea behind this is you can basically go    std::cout << departmentObj->getForeignKey()->getIdentifier();    ill post some code from my test project (chopped down for testing) at this point since im not sure if im making any seance.

-- sorry guys the code block here is bugging, so it will have to be paste bin.

List.cpp
http://pastebin.com/Le3fz5YF

List.h
http://pastebin.com/5yJYDM8N

Node.cpp
http://pastebin.com/Pgas8eju

Node.h
http://pastebin.com/TZPrEA4Q

Fac.cpp
http://pastebin.com/0EGeGhdq

dep.cpp
http://pastebin.com/G2yk6jCg

Main.cpp
http://pastebin.com/npiCC6wX

refrence loader
http://pastebin.com/n6UdsYmW

so basically it comes down to returning the memory address of an desired object through the list. clearly im not getting how to access the node and list class correctly to do this. the way i would like to be able to do this is just simply have a nice line of code that i can use to replace the addnode lines in my loader (ill post that for reference) it would look like this:

```
departmentList->AddNode(new Department(holder[0], holder[1], facultyList->getPkObjAdd(holder[2])));
```

but ofc the problem lies with how to return that objects memory address. if it has to be a virtual function, how do i allow it to return multiple object types like faculty and department?

im not sure if im making much seance, i hope someone can help me out. 
Thanks for your time!!
- quick edit, forgot dep and fac.cpp's

Comment: This is a scary unreadable wall of text. You should organise your thoughts first, then post a cohesive question about one specific problem.

Comment: Also, the code block here certainly isn't bugging. You're linking to entirely too much code as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey thought id pop back and post the solution incase anyone wonders in future. since im handling data types where i know the return value i decided to use:

void* getMe();

void* as you may or may not know is apointer to mem address. you can then convert it using

(Faculty*)facultyList->getPkMemAdd("PK");

hope it helps someone!!

Answer (score 1):

Have you included all of your code? It looks like you're missing some files (Fac.cpp includes Fac.h, but you don't seem to have posted that).

In any case, unless you've subclassed your Node class, there's no inheritance going on with that class: Node doesn't extend anything, and (as far as I could tell) nothing extends Node. Also, the way you've written it, Node contains a pointer to another Node, but no other data. If you changed the Node.h header so that it looked like:

```
#pragma once
#include <iostream>
#include "string"

using namespace std;

class Node
{
  public:
        Node();
        Node(Node* next);
        ~Node(void);

    // Member Functions
    Node* GetNextNode();
    void SetNextNode(Node* next);
    void * GetData();
    void SetData(void* data);

    // Virtual Functions
    virtual void DisplayContents() = 0;
        virtual string getIdentifier() = 0;
        virtual PROBLEM getMe() = 0;

  private:
        Node* nextNode;
        void* data;
};
```

Then added the functions GetData and SetData:

```
void SetData(void *data)
{
  this.data = data;
}

void * GetData()
{
  return this.data;
}
```

You would then be able to store something in each Node. You probably don't want data's type to be void*, you probably want to store strings. But the idea is the same.

As for virtual functions, the idea has purely to do with inheritance. The idea with virtual functions is that an object will always call its own version of a function, rather than its parent class's version. So if you have:

```
class Base
{
public:
  virtual void virtualFunc();
  void otherFunc();
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
  virtual void virtualFunc();
  void otherFunc();
};
```

I'll define these functions like so:

```
#include "inheritance.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void Base::virtualFunc()
{
  cout << "in Base::virtualFunc" << endl;
}

void Base::otherFunc()
{
  cout << "in Base::otherFunc" << endl;
}

void Derived::virtualFunc()
{
  cout << "in Derived::virtualFunc" << endl;
}

void Derived::otherFunc()
{
  cout << "in Derived::otherFunc" << endl;
}
```

Then you create some objects somewhere:

```
Derived *derived1 = new Derived();
Base *derived2 = new Derived();
```

If you call virtualFunc() on derived1 or on derived2 it will always call the copy defined in Derived, because it's declared virtual. If you call otherFunc() with derived1, it will call the version defined in Derived, because derived1 is declared as type Derived. However, derived2 is declared as Base, so if you call its otherFunc(), the copy defined in Base will be called instead. So if you have the following code:

```
#include "inheritance.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  Derived *derived1 = new Derived;
  Base *derived2 = new Derived;

  cout << "calling virtualFunc() with derived1: ";
  derived1->virtualFunc();

  cout << "calling virtualFunc() with derived2: ";
  derived2->virtualFunc();

  cout << "calling otherFunc() with derived1: ";
  derived1->otherFunc();

  cout << "calling otherFunc() with derived2: ";
  derived2->otherFunc();

  delete derived1;
  delete derived2;

}
```

You'll get this as output:

```
calling virtualFunc() with derived1: in Derived::virtualFunc
calling virtualFunc() with derived2: in Derived::virtualFunc
calling otherFunc() with derived1: in Derived::otherFunc
calling otherFunc() with derived2: in Base::otherFunc
```

In your Node class, you define some pure virtual functions, which are a special. These are set to 0 in the class definition, and the idea is that in your base class (in this case, Node), you can't define their functionality. Instead, you're saying that any derived classes MUST define functionality for these functions. Note that you can't directly create objects of a class with pure virtual functions. If you have a derived class that doesn't define these functions, you won't be able to directly create objects of that type, either, you'll need to subclass it somehow in order to do that.

I'm guessing that for this assignment you're supposed to subclass Node in a few different ways in order to store different types of data in different types of nodes.

Hope this helps!

Comment: hank you for your answer! Node is a base class for each of the other classes (eg fac, node) and it extended using virtual's like you have demonstrated. my problem is( using you example ) this:

Base* Base::virtualFunc()
{
  cout << "in Base::virtualFunc" << endl;
}

void Base::otherFunc()
{
  cout << "in Base::otherFunc" << endl;
}

Derived* Derived::virtualFunc()
{
  cout << "in Derived::virtualFunc" << endl;
}

 void Derived::otherFunc()
{
  cout << "in Derived::otherFunc" << endl;
}
but ofc using two different types of return values will break my virtual?